# What is the order in which files in the XAP archive are loaded into memory?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Are images (type content) loaded into memory when the wp7 app starts i.e. the main dll is loaded into memory or when first referenced from code. Are the loaded images cached automatically?

Also is there a way in visual studio to see the order in which files in the XAP are loaded into memory?

Comment: What's the problem? flahing images? null ref exception?

Answer (score 2):

Images with build action set to `Resource` are loaded up along with the main XAP at startup. Images with build action set to `Content` are loaded up when they are referenced.